# tikz externalization: list and make forces make to recompile the tikz images every time

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files, makefile

I'm trying to speed up my latex development by parallelising as much tasks as possible and by redoing as little work as possible on every run.

Amongst other things, I want to externalise my tikz images with the `list and make` option set. This allows me to recompile all the tikz images at once
using `make -j -f main.makefile`.

To automate this I use following makefile (simplified for purpose of this question):

```
main.pdf: main.tex
   pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode -draftmode -fmt=preamble main.tex
   make -j -s -f main.makefile
   pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode main.tex
```

One problem I have using this approach is that `make -j -s -f main.makefile` *always* recompiles *all* images, even when it is not necessary (when only some ir even none of the tikz images have been changed in `main.tex`).

It being so that the tikz images usually are taking the lions share
of my compilation time, this seems incredibly wasteful.

Is there a way to get around this? I would think it is trivial for tikz only to write the images that need to be rebuilt to the `makefile`.

### important update:

It appears as though `list and make` *does* work as it should except when
the `-fmt=preamble` flag is set (as I did in my makefile). However, to
create more speedup I would like to keep using my precompiled preamble.
Any way to get around this?

My preamble contains all my package inclusions and command definitions. The `\tikzexternalize` and `\tikzset` commands are place inside my dynamic preamble.

## MWE

Consider the following directory structure:

```
.
|- main.tex      # this is the main document
|- preamble.tex  # this is the preamble document
```

- `preamble.tex` contains all static stuff:

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{article}

  \usepackage[dutch]{babel}
  \usepackage[babel]{microtype}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  % ...
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}

  % tikz and pgf library loading and settings
  \usetikzlibrary{external}
  \pgfplotsset{compat = newest }

  % package settings
  \hypersetup { 
     % ...
  }
  ```

  % ...
  \def\preambleloaded{-- PRECOMILED PREAMBLE LOADED --}
- `main.tex` contains the dynamic preamble and the document:

  ```
  % load preamble if it wasn't precompiled
  \def\ifundefined#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax}             

  \ifundefined{preambleloaded}
      \typeout{!! PRECOMILED PREAMBLE NOT LOADED --}\input{preamble.tex}
  \else
      \typeout{\preambleloaded}
  \fi

  % tikz external settings
  \tikzexternalize[
      optimize=true,
      % system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -file-line-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"},
      % also works and is faster:
      system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -file-line-error -interaction=batchmode -fmt=preamble -jobname "\image" "\texsource"},
      mode=list and make
  ]

  \begin{document}
      some text...
      % ...
  \end{document}
  ```

Note the `system call` setting for tikz externalisation.

To precompile the preamble, the following command is used:

```
pdflatex -ini -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode -file-line-error -jobname="preamble" "&latex preamble.tex\dump" preamble.tex
```

To compile the document using the precompiled `fmt` file I use:

```
pdflatex      -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode -file-line-error -output-format=pdf -fmt=preamble main.tex
```

> The mwe is also downloadable [from dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zqb8jpdeyvy2s6e/mwe.zip).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70994/31416

Comment: I would not be surprised if the precompiled preamble simply does not fit in externalization mode: the externalization sets up (and requires) a different preamble. And I am unsure if this is still possible together with your `fmt` file

Comment: so nothing can be done?

Comment: Hard to say; I have never tried it. But it sounds a lot as if you would need to use a different precompiled preamble for the externalization - hopefully one which fits all. Perhaps you can create a minimal working example include the commands which generate the fmt files and we can experiment?

Comment: The MWE is up and I put it on dropbox too for anyone to download.

Comment: Using a combined format file would also speed up the individual image compilations. This is so because since `tikz` uses it's own format file for the external compilations, my `preamble.fmt` does not get used and thus must me *included* for every `tikz` run (because the `preambleloaded` is not set -- see `main.tex`). This is again slower. So merging the format files would give three speedups: one for the first run, one for each tikz picture that is built (in parallel using `make -j`) and one for the second run.

Comment: and also note that using `fmt=preamble` in the `external/system call` does seem to work as expected and speeds up the image compilation considerably.