# Not recompile unchanged pgfplots graph

Tags: pgfplots, compiling

I'm writing a document with many graphs containing a lot of data points. Many graphs are finished and I don't need to change them anymore. Since I am improving and correcting the text, I need to recompile often. Each time I have to recompile, all the graphs are recompiled as well and this process takes a huge amount of time.

**Is there a way to compile the graphs only once and then include them in the final pdf in subsequent compilations?**

Comment: related (duplicate?) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60434/draft-mode-for-pgfplots

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, fortunately it is! And it is even quite easy.

For this Christian has created a library called `external` which has made it into the `pgf`, `tikz` package and is accessible through that package.

Whatever, is shown below also works for `pgfplots` as they are typeset within a `tikzpicture` environment.

What it does is, the following:

Check if an image file corresponding to the currently reached image is found:

1. If image found, check whether the image code has changed, and if not, the image is inserted.
2. If image is not found or the image code has been changed, do the following:

   1. Invoke a new shell with your executable and create the image
   2. Insert image in the document

This means that for each image that is externalized you will get a new compiled document with additional log, aux files etc. I.e. many new files.
It is important to note that since `pgf` uses hashes of the image code to check whether a recreation of the image is necessary, it cannot determine whether any code in the pre-ample or elsewhere not in the image changes the resulting image. So sometimes it may be advantageous to delete the images.

A most basic example is to do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Load the library
\usetikzlibrary{external}
% Enable the library !!!>>> MUST be in the preamble <<<!!!!
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will create one additional file called `<document name>-figure0.pdf`. Which is the first occurring `tikzpicture` environment in the file.

This has the disadvantage of reading the `0` file even if you rearrange your `tikzpicture` environments.
For this there is a command: `\tikzsetnextfilename` which can be used to force the following `tikzpicture` environment to a specific file name.
This ensures the correct loading order of the figures. *I would encourage you to do this on each picture*.

So for instance this:

```
% Default the externalized name to 'hello'
\tikzsetnextfilename{hello}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red] (0,0) -- (-1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Lastly the `external` library creates the images within the current directory. This means that you will have a very cluttered folder of many files (as it compiles many *sub* documents only containing the images).

A common way to bypass this is to add a prefixed directory to the output of the files. You do that by the command: `\tikzsetexternalprefix` which is pretty self-explanatory. So a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Load the library
\usetikzlibrary{external}
% Enable the library
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

% Default all images in the subfolder `figs/`
\tikzsetexternalprefix{figs/}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[green] (0,0) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

% You are allowed to rearrange your images to separate folders
\tikzsetexternalprefix{figs/red/}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzsetexternalprefix{figs/blue/}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This can thus also be used to sort your images by chapter, or style, or etc..... :)

Otherwise search for the `external` tag here, or see the manual.

In general it is always a good custom to delete all your externalised images before doing your **final** compilation. This ensures that images are updated etc.

Comment: Just to clarify: TikZ checks if the figure that it shall process already exists and if yes, it doesn't reprocess it but just includes the already processed one, right? But what if I change the code of some TikZ figure? Do I then have to delete the corresponding, already processed figure to force reprocessing or is TikZ somehow recognizing by itself that it has to rebuild it?

Comment: Good question by @BenediktBauer. I had the same question. By the way with `\tikzsetexternalprefix{}` I will choose the path of the following TikZ pictures, right? Can I use it in the preamble? And `\tikzsetnextfilename{}` is used to name a file: it creates a "link" whit the following image so if I change order of figures, the filename will help to load the right image?

Comment: @R.M. Yes you can of course use `\tikzsetexternalprefix` in the preamble. That's what I do. The documentation doesn't say (at least I couldn't find it) if it recompiles if you change something, so I wouldn't count on it. Normally I have to delete the old image (I'm lazy so I just delete the folder).

Comment: @BenediktBauer I have updated the answer. In general, if you change the code you need, either to use the makefile solution or delete the images.

Comment: @zeroth I tried your to apply your explanations to my code in TeXShop and I get an error. It is said to check that system calls are enabled... What I have to do?

Comment: @R.M. you need to enable "-shell-escape" or "-write18" for your compilation step, try and search for "TeXShop shell escape" and you will definitely find something :)

Comment: @zeroth I compiled by terminal with the `-shell-escape`. Now it works fine! Thank you!

Comment: `externalize` now generates and checks against hashes for each tikzpicture; if you change something it will be rendered with the updates.

Comment: @G.H.Faust I have added the changes

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `externalize` library of `TikZ`, as the documentation of `pdfplots` suggests (7.1.1). You have to add this code to your preamble, everything else should work automatically:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

That means every picture is computed only once, and the built image is saved and reused the next time you compile.

You can even use a special directory, if you want:

```
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzext/]
```

This saves all your computed images to the path `tikzext/`

For `externalize` to work, you need to enable shell-escape (`write18`).