# Environment expansion, Tikz external library, caption and label

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I am LaTex newbie, please, be patient.

The great answer tells how to correctly work with `\tikzexternalize`:
[Problem with environment expansion and the Tikz external library.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/problem-with-environment-expansion-and-the-tikz-external-library)

My question is: how do I extend the code to add `\caption` and `\label` parameters?

EDIT: Thanks to `gernot` my code works fine:

```
\NewEnviron{mytikz}[3][]%
  {\begin{figure}[htp]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
   \BODY
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{#2}%
   \label{#3}%
   \end{figure}%
  }

% Elemcube command taken from: http://blog.dorian-depriester.fr/latex/tikz/empilements-de-cubes-sous-tikz

\newcommand{\elemcube}[4][white]
{

    \draw [fill=#1!30,very thin] (#2+1,#3,#4) -- ++(0,1,0) -- ++(0,0,1) -- ++(0, -1, 0) -- cycle; 
    \draw [fill=#1!40,very thin] (#2,#3+1,#4) -- ++(1,0,0) -- ++(0,0,1) -- ++(-1, 0, 0) -- cycle; 
    \draw [fill=#1!10,very thin] (#2,#3,#4) -- ++(1,0,0) -- ++(0,1,0) -- ++(-1, 0, 0) -- cycle;  

}

\begin{mytikz} [x=(90:0.2cm), y=(0:0.2cm), z=(40:0.1cm), axis/.style={->,blue,thick}]{A sample 3-d array.}{fig:flyx}

 \def\xx{8}
 \def\yy{8}
 \def\zz{8}

\foreach \z in{\zz,...,0}
{   
   \foreach \x in{0,...,\xx}
   {
    \foreach \y in{0,...,\yy}
   {
    \elemcube{\x}{\y}{\z}
    }
}
}   
    % draw axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (\xx+1.5,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$lat$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,\yy+1.5,0) node[anchor=north west]{$lon$};
    \draw[axis] (\xx+1,\yy+1,0) -- (\xx+1,\yy+1,\zz+1.5) node[anchor=south]{\large $time$};
\end{mytikz}
```

Comment: You don't *need* to follow the answer you link to to use `\tikzexternalize`, you can simply place `\usetikzlibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize` in the preamble and then place your `tikzpicture` environments inside `figure` environments with the appropriate `\caption`, `\label`.  [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76444/106162) gives some basics of using the `external` TikZ library or check the Externalization Library section of the [`pgf`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for the thorough documentation.

Comment: In response to your edit, you have `]]{A sample 3-d array.}` when you mean to have `]{A sample 3-d array.}` so the first token after the optional argument is `]` which is taken to be the first mandatory argument rather than `{A sample 3-d array.}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you don't need to use the `xargs` package. In this case you can define a `mytikz` environment just as

```
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{mytikz}[3][]%
  {\begin{figure}[htp]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
   \BODY
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{#2}%
   \label{#3}%
   \end{figure}%
  }
```

and use it as

```
\begin{mytikz}[tikz options for your drawing]{caption}{label}
... tikz commands ...
\end{mytikz}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{mytikz}[3][]%
  {\begin{figure}[htp]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
   \BODY
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{#2}%
   \label{#3}%
   \end{figure}%
  }

\begin{document}
\tikzset{external/force remake=true}
\begin{mytikz}[every path/.style={red}]{my caption}{figlabel}
\draw(0,0) circle (1cm);
\node {hello world};
\end{mytikz}

See my great figure~\ref{figlabel}.

\end{document}
```