# Equivalent to graphicx draft/demo option for tables

Tags: tables, compiling, draft

I am looking for a way to exclude tables from compilation when I am in draft mode (technically I want to create a boolean such as `drafttables` that would exclude tables when active). Usually I have tables in a separate file at the end of the document and just exclude it from compilation while working on the document. But now I need to put many many tables inside the document as floats, and because the tables are rather complicated, compilation takes a long time.

Is it possible to create a macro that just puts a placeholder instead of the table, similar to the option of the `graphicx` package? A bonus would be if the placeholder would have similar dimensions as the table, so that the layout stays the same.

Comment: You can't get the table dimensions without compiling them, so having a placeholder is almost out of the question. One could think of saving the table dimensions in the aux file in case the table is compiled.

Comment: @egreg Simply excluding the table would be easy with the `ifdraft` package, e.g. wrap the whole float in `\ifdraft{\relax}{\begin{table}...` but that would be really annoying for the layout. The tables won't change, so taking the dimensions values from the aux file after an initial compile sounds like a good idea.

Comment: This sounds a bit tricky --- how does your "complicated table" look like? Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmhughes answer made me realise that any form of "automatic" table size recognition is just overkill. First, my tables are usually textwidth-wide, hence there is not a massive variation in size. Second, even if the size is a few cm's longer or shorter it does not really matter. So my strategy is as follows:

- Create a new `ifnotables` conditional that can be activated by the
  documentclass via `notables`
- Create a few predefined empty tables: `\fulltable` is on a extra page float, `\halftable` is half the size...`\thirdtable`, `\quartertable` etc.

The table can then be set by `\ifnotables{\halftable}{\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}`. The advantage is that, when set in a table float, captions, labels etc. remain the same which allows for a decent layout: only the actual table is missing.

```
\documentclass[%
notables
]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs,lmodern}

\makeatletter
% Provide new conditionals
\newif\if@notables
\DeclareOption{notables}{%
  \@notablestrue
}
\ProcessOptions*\relax
\newcommand*{\ifnotables}{%
  \if@notables
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% create dummy tables
\newcommand{\fulltable}{%
 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}
  \hspace{-.5em}\pgfpicture\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\textwidth}{23cm}}%
  \pgfusepath{stroke}\endpgfpicture%
 \end{tabular*}
}
\newcommand{\halftable}{%
 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}
  \hspace{-.5em}\pgfpicture\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\textwidth}{11.5cm}}%
  \pgfusepath{stroke}\endpgfpicture%
 \end{tabular*}
}
\newcommand{\thirdtable}{%
 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}
  \hspace{-.5em}\pgfpicture\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\textwidth}{7cm}}%
  \pgfusepath{stroke}\endpgfpicture%
 \end{tabular*}
}
\newcommand{\quartertable}{%
 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}
  \hspace{-.5em}\pgfpicture\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\textwidth}{5cm}}%
  \pgfusepath{stroke}\endpgfpicture%
 \end{tabular*}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{First table}
\label{tab:first}
        \ifnotables{\thirdtable}{%
         \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc}
         \toprule
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
       }
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!b]
\centering
\caption{Second table}
\label{tab:second}
        \ifnotables{\quartertable}{%
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccc}
        \toprule
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
       }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The size of the dummies can of course be fine tuned. I usually have my tables stored in separate tex files, hence by creating a command such as:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\mytable}[2][]{%
 \ifstrempty{#1}{%
  \input{#2}
  }{%
  \ifnotables{#1}{\input{#2}}%  
 }
}
```

I can make the code in the float tidier and the specification of a dummy table is optional:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{First table}
\label{tab:first}
   \mytable[\halftable]{table2}
\end{table}
```

Comment: This is obviously useful for *writing* a text, but it doesen't really help for *layouting* a book with many table-floats which have to be arranged properly. For the latter it would be crucial to do as egreg suggests above: Measure the tables in one run and use the precise dimensions to reserve the appropriate space in the draft run.

Answer (score 3):

I've borrowed some work from [Draft mode for pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60434/draft-mode-for-pgfplots) in the solution below.

If you use

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
```

then all the `tables` will not appear. If you use

```
\documentclass{article}
```

then they'll appear as usual.

I've used the `verbatim` package just for the `comment` environment.

Measuring the dimensions of the table would be tricky- perhaps this will help someone go in that direction.

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\makeatletter
\@tempswafalse
\def\@tempa{draft}
\@for\next:=\@classoptionslist\do
  {\ifx\next\@tempa\@tempswatrue\fi}
\if@tempswa % draft option is active
    \renewenvironment{table}{\comment}{\endcomment}
    \fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

hello world

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{}
        \label{tab:first}
        \begin{tabular}{rcl}
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{}
        \label{tab:second}
        \begin{tabular}{rcl}
            right & center & left \\
            right & center & left 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

## Alternative

Or else you might prefer to load `tikz` or `pgf` and then use the following in the `\ifdraft` check

```
\renewenvironment{tabular}{%
\pgfpicture\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{3cm}{3cm}}%
     \pgfusepath{stroke}\endpgfpicture%
\comment}{\endcomment}
```

which gives

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for this. I used your idea and create some automisation for it.