# Load Graphics as Empty Boxes for Positioning and Quick Compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, compiling, draft

Is there a package that loads all images (tikz, pgfplots, images, etc.) only as empty boxes? This would greatly speed up compilation of documents when making edits to the content and layout when the positioning of positioning is needed, but the adjusting of the actual graphical content is not.

Comment: The `graphicx` package understands the `draft` option that does exactly this (it replaces the actual image with a box if its size and the filename). This does not work for TikZ pictures, though. A work-around would be to `external`ize these pictures first …

Comment: have you seen [Draft mode for pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60434)

Comment: Close enough to the linked question to be treated as a dupe, I think