# Work on one figure in draft mode for PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, draft

this is my first post in this forum, so please don't be too harsh if I do any mistake.

From the post of the added link in the end of my question I got the information to use

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/.code={\includegraphics{#1}}}
```

to enter a real draft mode for PGFPlots, which works quite nicely.

So far I couldn't find an answer on how to exit draft mode just for one figure, when I'm working on it.

Can someone help me out?
I add an example on how I include my figures. I'm using tikz externalized mode.
So far I've just found solutions for the graphics package as

```
\includegraphics[draft=false]{example-image-b}.
```

But as I don't use this command to include my tikz figures I can't use it. Right?
I've tried a couple of combinations, but it doesn't work so far.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Jakob

Preamble:

```
    \pgfplotsset{
    invoke before crossref tikzpicture={\tikzexternaldisable},
    invoke after crossref tikzpicture={\tikzexternalenable},
    width=14cm,compat=1.12,
    }
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/.code={\includegraphics{#1}}}

    \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
    \tikzexternalize[prefix=3-diagrams/] % activate with a name prefix
```

diagram code:

```
        \tikzsetnextfilename{hyfo_tof}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfkeys{draft=false}   % this is a non-working idea of mine.. maybe someone knows the proper command to enter here?
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/} % another non-working idea
        \begin{axis}[]
                \addplot+ table[x=JM_070_T,y=JM_070_TOF]{hyfo_tof.dat};
                \label{hyfo_tof:JM_070}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{...}
        \label{hyfo_tof}
        \end{figure}
```

[Draft mode for pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60434/draft-mode-for-pgfplots?rq=1)