# Compiling a main document with many TikZ subfiles efficiently

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, subfiles

What would be the most efficient way to compile a document of the `article` class with many `TikZ` subfiles?

In the main document, I have added `\usepackage{standalone}` and then `\includestandalone` for the individual subfiles.

1. Would it be better to add the options `subpreambles = true`, `sort =
   true`, and trim all the `TikZ` preambles from the main document?
2. Or should I not use those options and keep all the `TikZ` preambles
   in both the main `.tex` file and the subfiles?

Which method would speed up compiling?  If neither of these methods are truly efficient, what should I do instead?

As it stands now, my document is around `60` pages but it takes a few minutes to compile.  I have over 30 `.eps` figures and over 30 `TikZ` subfiles.  Besides the `TikZ` code, everything else is pretty standard `LaTeX`.

The document class for the subfiles is `standalone` with the option `convert = false`.

One of the other problems that slows down compilation is the fact that every `standalone` picture is compiled when the main document is compiled.  However, there may have been nothing change with 95% of the pictures.

Main example doc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
text here
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includestandalone{test}
\end{figure}
text here
\end{document}
```

test example doc

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) circle[radius = .35cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look into tikz-external (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-external) at least for the TiKZ stuff that should be exactly what you are looking for

Comment: @sheß is there a specific thread you have in mind I should look at?

Comment: it's actually pretty streight forwards, except for a few minor problems you might encounter depending on what exactly you're doing. Basically, what you need to do is to load the library via `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` and run pdflatex (or whatever you're using) with the option `-shell-escape`. A short introduction is given here: http://olezfdtd.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/precompile-pgfplots-using-tikzexternalize/

Comment: Although tikz externalization works, I find it incredibly slow. Even if a figure already exists and it is not recompiled, the compilation time or the main document is drastically increased, compared to just including an pdf image created as a standalone tikzpicture.

Comment: @Markus This is very odd since `tikz-external` does exactly that: rendering the tikz picture into a PDF and including that.

Comment: @sheß "a few minor problems" is really a matter of sacrificing a goat at the right time of year. Usually everything is just fine, agreed. Sometimes things crash and burn spectacularly though.

Comment: @dustin I understand that your have a frustrating attempt to fix the problems at hand just behind of you. However, it is hard (if not impossible) to tell what is going on and what the problem is. Can you reduce the problem to some minimum working example such that we can understand and analyze the problem?

Comment: It seems as if you are mixing two approaches to generate separate output images: the standalone package and the tikz external library. One should be sufficient. Without have the time to investigate deeply, I assume that you could drop the `standalone` package and use only external. In this case, you would need to rewrite `line.tex` such that it contains *only* the picture, nothing else. The alternative approach would be to drop `external` and rely on `standalone` only. Others will be able to say more on this approach.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I only tried `external` due to a suggestion sheB.  As of now, I am simply using only `standalone` in my document, but whenever I compile the main file, all of the `standalone` files are compiled as well when they may have not been altered.  This slows down the compilation time.  My original question was how to to avoid this and how to consolidate the preambles.  I am going to edit the post and remove everything about external for clarity of the question.

Comment: dustin, you should still provide a minimal working example.

Answer (score 4):

I use the suggestion in [zeroth's discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40516/externalization-to-other-format-makefile-add-new-rules-to-the-makefile).
The discussion is for **pdflatex**.

However, I use **xelatex**, and I only test the methods by **texlive** on **Linux x64** system.

here is my way to make it works for **xelatex** compiler:

1. In the document preamble after `\usepackage{tikz}`:

   ```
   \usepackage{tikz}
     \usetikzlibrary{external}
     \tikzexternalize[figure list=false,prefix=tikz/]
       % make tikz externalize and store in directory "tikz"
     \tikzset{external/system call={xelatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape 
       -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}} 
       % to let xelatex work
   ```

   and use the command `xelatex -shell-escape xxxxxxx.tex` to compile the picture externalized. (Till now the normal `xelatex xxxxxxx.tex` command would return errors)
2. Once all independent pdf files compiled, normal `xelatex xxxxxxx.tex` should works as usual.

It's not perfect way to do tikz figure externalized because **the options here cannot recognize whether the externalized pdf files are identical to new tikz figure**.

Comment: I will check this out.  It may take me a few days to test this though.

Comment: Maybe you could just tell what platform and compiler you use? That may help others to find the answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04, 64bit and I use Emacs with AUCTeX and Latexmk.