# TikZ: Printing press cannot print document due to RGB colors, layers and transparency

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, printing

The place I print my thesis needs the PDF file to conform to certain demands. Demands I was not aware of prior to sending them the document.

So, here is the challenge:

Using PGF/TikZ how can I bulk change colors to CMYK and, if possible, flatten layered figures while retaining the visual properties I have made them with? I am, for example, placing scale bars on images and spy nodes of images in a foreground layer and the images themselves on the main layer.

Comment: I really don't get some of these printers. Can you change your printer because they should be able to change these on the preflight. Here are some related questions; http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=CMYK+[tikz]

Comment: I am rather annoyed. I do not think I can because this is all paid for by the university and deals are made, contracts signed and all that jazz. I have tried changing the document to CMYK, and I will see what they say to the new document.

Comment: One (bad) workaround is to externalize your figures and then convert the pdf resulting from each figure to a hi-res PNG. This should circunvent problems with layers and transparencies, and perhaps it will solve the CMYK issue too. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40516/externalization-to-other-format-makefile-add-new-rules-to-the-makefile could help here.

Comment: You could try [jmakepdfx](http://ctan.org/pkg/jmakepdfx) which uses ghostscript, but you may encounter problems with the transparency. (Since the process involves conversion to PostScript which doesn't support transparency.)

Comment: Please check if this works: load `xcolor` before TikZ and add the `cmyk` option. If I understand the documentation of `xcolor` and its use by TikZ correctly, this should convert all colors TikZ uses to CMYK.